# Error reporting in JSP with the switch statement nested HTML code

Tags: java

This is my JSP Code snippet which having Error.

```
 <%switch (1){%>
       <%case 1:%>
        switch 1
      <%break;%>
      <%case 2:%>
        switch 2
      <%break;%>
    <%}%>
```

Error reporting is

> "Syntax error on token "{", SwitchLabels expected after this token"

I hope somebody can help me!
I think my code is right,but it unable to compile class for JSP!

Answer (score 0):

I'm so happy to solve this problem. When I check the source of this jsp mapping servlet.java. I found source code did not have correct syntax, so it was unable to compile class for this jsp. The wrong syntax as follows: After "switch {" unable write state except for case. The root cause is "the blank character" conver to java code is "out.write("\t \t");" So I changemy jsp code,delete blank character an code in line,as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dtrE.png)